# How to write HTTPClient requests to access ASP.Net Core Web App methods from WPF Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

After creating the controller and model classes in a ASP.Net Core Application, now I created a WPF Application in which I would like to implement the methods written in the previous project. However, my lack of knowledge about this really holds me back.

So at this point, I have two projects in my VS solution:

**RecipeAPI**, which is a ASP.Net Core Application and **RecipeUI1**, which is a Windows Forms Application

Inside the RecipeAPI project, I already have the model and controller classes made and now I have to create a prototype UI in which the functionality should be implemented.

```
        [Route("v1/recipe/{recipeBy}")]
[HttpGet()]
public List<Recipe> GetRecipes(string recipeBy)
{
    using (var con = _connFactory())
    {
        con.Open();
        return con.Query<Recipe>("SELECT * FROM dbo.Recipe WHERE RecipeBy = @recipeBy", new { recipeBy }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Let's take this method. Using this, I would like to populate a ListBox that I created in the WPF Application

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    static async Task<Recipe> GetProductAsync(string recipeBy)
    {
        Recipe recipe = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"v1/recipe/{recipeBy}");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            recipe = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Recipe>();
        }
        return recipe;
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        // Update port # in the following line.
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64195/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

            // Get the product
            recipe = await GetProductAsync("Test Person");
            GetProductAsync(recipe);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is the content from **Form.cs**. I followed a tutorial while writing this code but as it wasn't quite what I needed, this is all I was able to do. Also this line of code has the following error:

> ```
>             GetProductAsync(recipe);
> ```
>
> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

I am even sure that the code I wrote in the GetProdcutAsync() method is useful for what I am trying to do - at this point it's quite foggy for me. How can I properly use the HTTPClient request for my case? Also, what should be written inside the ListBox method so the list of items will be visible?

Comment: You're calling `GetProductAsync` twice. It that's your intention and not a copying error, use `await GetProductAsync(recipe);` just like the previous line. Apart from that, what's the question?

Comment: The question is what is the best way to use the GetProductAsync method to populate a ListBox?

Comment: You alredy called it correctly - `recipe = await GetProductAsync("Test Person");`. Remove the `new Recipe()` call as you're replacing that value with the method's result. You could just write `var recipe = await GetProductAsync("Test Person");`

Comment: For example here: `private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add();
        }` What do I have to call to actually populate the listbox? As I currently have no method written for that.

Comment: So I used this: `listBox1.DataSource = GetProductAsync("Test Person").Result;` but I am receiving the following: `An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set`